# Ignore base href on preg_match using PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the following preg_match to replace any html links to another url it works except it also changes the base_href value - I want it to totally ignore the base href value

```
$message = preg_replace("/href=\"http\:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/*)?)/","href=\"http://www.site.com/system/link_tracker.php?URL=$1&ID={$ID}\"", $message);
```

Any ideas how to edit this to only look at a href and not the base href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$message = preg_replace("/<a([^>]+)href=\"http\:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/*)?)/",
                        "<a$1href=\"http://www.site.com/system/link_tracker.php?URL=$2&ID={$ID}\"", $message);
```

Comment: Any idea how to alter your preg_replace to allow urls like http://www.facebook.com/user/12131

At the moment only those like http://www.facebook.com seem to work